# Map orientation in print composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I need to create a layout in which the vertices of the map in the layout coincide with the vertices of a rectangle of a grid that is oriented differently from the map on which it is overlayed: what can be the correct way to do it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by orientation you mean the map rotation you can use the 'Oriented minimum bounding box' tool on your polygon layer with the CRS of your basemap. It will create a field called 'angle'. You can then insert this angle using a custom expression in the map item properties in the 'map rotation' field. Since it is your atlas feature(probably) you can grab it by using the expression: `"angle"`. You might have to use `replace("angle",',','.')` since map rotation only uses . as a delimiter.

Comment: Sorry, updated comment:Thanks for Your answer. I tried, according to Your advice, with a single rectangle (map sheet): run the Oriented minimum bounding box tool from geoprocessing menu and grabbed the "angle" value (90.48xxxx) for the specific feature converted to -0.49 as rotation map value. Setting map extent using x, y min / x, y max I have a feedback value in the scale factor of 1: 9997 (instead of 1: 10000 as expected): it may be due to the different approximation (2 vs 6) between "map rotation field" and the value of the "angle" field?

Comment: I was having the same problem with the scale not fitting the actual desired/given one. My maps were fixed at 25000 and all varied by +/-50. I don't know why but I guess it might be,as you mentioned, because of the map rotation only taking 2 characters after the comma OR maybe because of CRS issues. I decided to stick with the small scale variations since they were so little.